# repeat Record with Select in SQl 2008

Tags: sql

Declare @NoofRept int

select id,Name from tbl_Name where id=1

```
id  |Name
1   |XXXXXXX
```

My Requirement this 
repeat this Record @NoofRept Time

```
id  |Name
1   |XXXXXXX
1   |XXXXXXX
1   |XXXXXXX
1   |XXXXXXX
```

Comment: means whatever you pass in variable @NoofRept it should give you record that many times?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat the record less than a maximum of 2047 you could use the table `Master..spt_values`, this is a system table and the type P has sequential numbers from 0 to 2047:

```
DECLARE @NoofRept INT = 10

SELECT  t.ID, t.Name
FROM    tbl_Name t
        CROSS JOIN Master..spt_Values v
WHERE   t.ID = 1
AND     v.Type = 'P'
AND     v.Number BETWEEN 1 AND @NoofRept
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dadb4/3)**

If you need more than this then you will need to `CROSS JOIN` tables to get the number of rows required:

```
SELECT  ID, Name
FROM    tbl_Name
        CROSS JOIN 
        (   SELECT  rpt = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.Number)
            FROM    Master..spt_Values a
                    CROSS JOIN Master..spt_Values b
                    --CROSS JOIN Master..spt_values c
                    --CROSS JOIN Master..spt_values d
        ) v
WHERE   ID = 1
AND     v.rpt BETWEEN 1 AND @NoofRept
```

*Uncomment joins as required*

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dadb4/4)**

Answer (score 0):

Untested pseudo code, but something like this might do the trick:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
DELCARE @i int; 
SET @i = 1;

SET @sql = 'select id,Name from tbl_Name where id=1'

WHILE @i < @NoofRept
BEGIN
  SET @sql = @sql + 'UNION select id,Name from tbl_Name where id=1'

  SET @i = @i + 1;
END

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```