# SQL Need Inner Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please note that what I have below the system already has in place so changing it will take time. As such, I know the best way is to normalize but...

I have the followng 2 tables

```
Tbl1

CompId      CommaList
------      --------
2           '122','54','90'   
54          '53','76'
34          '87' 
22          '98'


Tbl2

ID     ClientId   
--     --------
1      122
2      76 
3      87
4      98
```

What I need is to join Tbl1 and Tbl2 and then return the CompId and ID

The join should be done from tbl2.ClientId with tbl1.CommaList (which is a comma delimted list from which I need to find a matching value from.

Hope this make sense.

```
    select tbl1.CompId, tbl2.Id
    from tbl1  join tbl2 on CommaList = tbl2.ClientId
```

Obviously this will not work as they are of different types and I need furthermore find the list within CommaList.

The final result should look like:

```
ID       CompId
--       ------
1        2 
2        54
3        34
4        22
```

Comment: You will need to de-serialize the data contained in Tbl1's CommaList first.

Comment: ... And this is why you're not supposed to use multi-value columns

Comment: `Tbl1` should have a row for each `CompId,ClientId` not a single row per `CompId` with all the clients stuffed into one value.

Comment: Does your `CommaList` actually have "'" (apostrophes) around the number strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: *Storing comma-separated lists in a database column is a code smell, and generally indicates you need to normalize your database structure.  Please **do not** do this in your code if at all possible.*

---

You can solve by matching client id values inside the comma-separated list with `LIKE` clause:

```
select
  t2.ID, t1.CompId
from Tbl1 t1
join Tbl2 t2 on t1.CommaList
  like '%''' + cast(t2.ClientId as varchar(10)) + '''%'
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d416/6

Comment: To Original Poster: Please note **Disclaimer**.

Comment: Needs to normalize (not  denormalize)

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly you want to do this with a join table, expanding CommaList. That is, you want a table with

```
 Tbl3
 CompID      ClientID
 2            122
 2             54
 2             90
 54            53
```

etc.

Some databases let you store `CommaList` as an array and use an `IN` operator, but that's both non-standard and inefficient. (You can also do a string search like mellamokb's answer, but notice his disclaimer is the same as mine.) Now you can just do

```
SELECT id, compID FROM Tbl3 NATURAL JOIN Tbl2;
```

Except in special cases, avoid denormalized data like `Tbl1`.

Comment: In view of mekkamokb comment, correct to 
`SELECT id, compID FROM Tbl3 JOIN Tbl2 ON Tbl3.ClientID=Tbl2.ClientID;` 
I knew there was a reason to like PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

I have posted a solution which I haven't tested but should work. It feels wrong doing the way and I now feel unclean by encouraging you with an answer:

```
SELECT tbl1.CompId, tbl2.Id
FROM tbl1  
  JOIN tbl2 ON CommaList LIKE '%''' + CAST(tbl2.ClientId AS VARCHAR) + '%'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select tbl1.CompId, tbl2.Id
from tbl1, tbl2 
where CHARINDEX('''' + CONVERT(varchar(50),tbl2.ClientId) + '''', CommaList)<> 0
```

Comment: You need to be careful about controlling the beginning and end of the match - for example, by including the single quotes `'`.  Otherwise this solution is open to matching false positives when one clientId is a substring of another.  For example, if commaList contains `871`, then a clientId of `87` would match: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ccc2/1

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for clue!

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you couldn't use the `Char Index` or `like` solutions you could split the comma list and then join. For example if you needed to do the conceptual equivalent of

> from tbl2 on CommaList = tbl2.ClientId **LEFT** join tbl1  join

```
with split as (

SELECT 
       CompID,
       Substring(commalist, number, Charindex(',', commalist + ',', number) 
                                    - number) 
                                                                   AS clientID 
FROM   tbl1  
       JOIN master..spt_values v 
         ON number <= Len(commalist) 
            AND Substring(',' + commalist, number, 1) = ',' 
WHERE  v.type = 'P' )

SELECT 

    split.CompId,
    split.clientID,
    tbl2.id


FROM 

  split
  LEFT JOIN tbl2 
  on tbl2.clientID = split.clientID
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/727d7/9)

**Notes:**

- I didn't bother with dealing with the quote delimited part but you could do that easily by `replace(commalist,'''','')`
- As is, this only works on values of commalist that are <= 2047 in length. If you're dealing with larger lists you can use [GarethD's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048425/garethd) second [example in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15294425/119477) to generate a larger numbers tables